# Ascendng and descending by date and by name at the list of the cards

Tags: javascript, angular, sorting

I have some cards and two sections, and every section has two buttons.

## HTML

```
<div *ngFor='let card of cards'>
{{ card.name }}
{{ card.date }}
</div>

<button *ngFor='let item of items' (click)='byNameOrDate()'>
    <i class='checker' *ngIf='isCheckedForItem'></i>   
    {{ item.name }} 
</button>

<button *ngFor='let sort of sorts' (click)='byAscOrDes()'> 
    <i class='checker' *ngIf='isCheckedForSort'></i>  
    {{ sort.name }} 
</button>
```

## TS

```
cards = [
{ 
name: 'AAA',
date: '20.05.2007',
checked: true
},
{ 
name: 'CCC',
date: '25.08.2018',
checked: false
},
{ 
name: 'BBB',
date: '05.08.2001',
checked: false
}
]

items = [
{ 
name: 'Name',
sorting: 'ASC',
checked: true
},
{ 
name: 'Date',
sorting: 'ASC',
checked: false
}
]

sorts = [
{ 
name: 'Ascending',
checked: true
},
{ 
name: 'Descending',
checked: false
}
]
```

Also I have 4 ready function for the sorting.

## TS

```
sortNameAscending();
sortNameDescending();
sortDateAscending();
sortDateDescending();
```

---

How code this in the most clean way `byNameOrDate()` and `byAscOrDes()` for sorting these cards by the **Name** and by the **Date**, depending of the chosen order.
Option with multiple `if else` looks ugly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, don't create so many methods, if-else etc.. 
you can use following, which will help you sort on whatever key passed and asc/desc :

```
const data=[
  {key:1,value:7},
  {key:2,value:2},
  {key:5,value:1},
  {key:3,value:3},
  {key:4,value:6}  
];

function comparer(key,asc){
  return data.sort((a,b)=>{
  return asc ? a[key] - b[key]:b[key] - a[key];
});

}

console.log(comparer('key',true));
console.log(comparer('value',false));
```

Comment: more or less. but thanks to your post I went on the right way. best regards!